# Calling function inside function returns 0

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 functions. If I call my first function from outside of the functions, it works. It gives the right value. Now if I call my first function inside my second function, it returns me with a value of 0.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Could someone please point me into the right direction here? Much appreciated!

```
def standaardprijs(afstandKM):
    totaalPrijs = 0
    if afstandKM < 50:
        kmPrijs = 0.8
        totaalPrijs += kmPrijs * afstandKM
        return(totaalPrijs)

    if afstandKM > 50:
        totaalPrijs = totaalPrijs + 15
        kmPrijs = 0.6
        totaalPrijs += kmPrijs * afstandKM
    return totaalPrijs

def ritprijs(leeftijd, weekendrit, afstandKM):
    totaalPrijs = 0
    totaaalPrijs = standaardprijs(afstandKMInp)
    print(totaalPrijs)
    # Leeftijd
    if leeftijd >= 12 and leeftijd <= 65:

        if weekendRit == 'j':
            TP2 = totaalPrijs / 0.35
            return TP2

        else:
            TP2 = totaalPrijs / 0.3
            return TP2


    else:
        if weekendRit == 'j':
            TP2 = totaalPrijs / 0.4
            return TP2

        else:
            #geen korting
            TP2 = totaalPrijs
            return TP2

afstandKMInp = eval(input('Hoeveel KM gaat u reizen?'))
weekendRit = input('Weekendrit? j/n')
leeftijd = int(input('Leeftijd: '))
ritprijs2 = ritprijs(leeftijd, weekendRit, afstandKMInp)
print(ritprijs2)
```

Comment: Your code snippet is fairly complicated (and being not written in English is very hard to comprehend). Can you please create [MCVE]?

Comment: @Sone Name, I rolled back the edits, changing your question code makes answers obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have a typo `totaaalPrijs` is not `totaalPrijs` so all you need to do is to change to:

```
 totaalPrijs = standaardprijs(afstandKMInp)
```

Also you should not use *eval*, cast *input* to int:

```
 afstandKMInp = int(input('Hoeveel KM gaat u reizen?'))
```

You can also simplify `if leeftijd >= 12 and leeftijd <= 65` using a chained comparison:

```
    if 12 <= leeftijd <= 65:
```

And you don't need to declare variables in python so you can remove `totaalPrijs = 0`

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Now I got a new problem tho, it's not registering leeftijd somehow. In my function the variable leeftijd is black, weekendrit and afstandKM are both grey. No idea what it means. But it's not picking up on my leeftijd if's. Any idea? EDIT: PEP8 error. Shadows leeftijd from outer scoop.

Comment: @SomeName, because again `weekendRit !=  weekendrit`, a good reason why using lowercase and underscores for your variable names is a good idea, your code works as the function is using the  `weekendRit` you declared outside the function in the global namespace

Comment: Wow, okay good call. Sorry just started python. Edited in main post. But that does not explain why leeftijd is not working? If I enter j together with leeftijd 16 it should return/print TP2 but I'm getting nothing

Comment: @SomeName, don't keep editing the question,  your initial question has been resolved, instead of editing the question you should ask a new one but I would recommend you look at  your code and make sure all the names align. Use lowercase and underscores for variable names as per the pep8 style guide  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/.

Answer (score 1):

`ritprijs(leeftijd, weekendRit, afstandKMInp)`

This line has no side effects. It returns a value but you never assign it to anything.

You should assign its return value to a variable:

```
some_value = ritprijs(leeftijd, weekendRit, afstandKMInp)
print(some_value)
```

Comment: Edited my code. Now it still gives me 0 as the output. + Since I have a return on every possible outcome, I shouldn't have to print from outside my functions?

Comment: @SomeName, if you are running the code outside a shell you will need to print to see the return values

Comment: Running in PyCharm. But I'm getting 2 results now, both 0. So my return is working